# Easy way to spring inject classes instead of returning new

Tags: java, spring, selenium, dependency-injection, jbehave

I currently have selenium tests running using jbehave and spring. My pattern is a story file > steps file > page file.

However I think the way I am returning new page files is not very clean, I believe these pages can be injected via spring but I need help implementing this.

My beans:

```
<bean id="driverProvider" class="org.jbehave.web.selenium.PropertyWebDriverProvider">
<bean>

<bean id="pageFactory"class="com.automation.pages.Pages
    <constructor-arg ref="driverProvider" />
</bean>
```

In my Pages class:

```
public class Pages {

    private final WebDriverProvider webDriverProvider;

    public Pages(WebDriverProvider webDriverProvider) {
        this.webDriverProvider = webDriverProvider;
    }

    public HomePage newHomePage() {
        return new HomePage(webDriverProvider);
    }

    public ContactPage newContactPage() {
        return new ContactPage(webDriverProvider);
    }
}
```

And my BasePage class:

```
public class BasePage {

protected HomePage homePage;
protected ContactPage contactPage;

public BasePage(PageFactory pageFactory) {
        homePage = pageFactory.newHomePage();
        contactPage = pageFactory.newContactPage();
}
```

And then from my Steps file I just extend BasePage so I have access to the protected pages.

Ideally I would like to remove the need for the pagefactory and/or basepage and let Spring to the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring for method injection.

Make your base class abstract and add an abstract method `public abstract ContactPage newPhoneLandingPage()`.

In your bean configuration add `<lookup-method name="newPhoneLandingPage" bean="newPhoneLandingPage">` to your bean where `newPhoneLandingPage` is your prototype bean.

Spring will wire the code, so if the method is called an new (`prototype`) instance will be returned.

Comment: I have managed to use the @Autowired annotation on the field declaration  whereever I need it. This means there is no need for the BasePage and PageFactory now.

However I do have many beans for each step and page file and I've read somewhere about custom annotations in spring.

I wonder if I could utilise this so I could just annotate each class and cut down the beans I have?